# How to use loop within foreach in php to add numbers

Tags: php

I am using php and have the following structure

```
<?php if(!empty($bids)): ?>
  <?php foreach ($bids as $bid):?>
     <tr>
         <td><?php if($bid['Bid']['debit'] > 0) : ?><?php echo $bid['Bid']['debit']; ?><?php else: ?>&nbsp;<?php endif; ?></td>
         <td><?php if($bid['Bid']['credit'] > 0) : ?><?php echo $bid['Bid']['credit']; ?><?php else: ?>&nbsp;<?php endif; ?></td>
     </tr>
  <?php endforeach; ?>
<?php endif;?>
```

Now i need to calculate the sum total in each case. I know its easy but not getting how to use loop within the `foreach` to calculate the total value. Please suggest how to do that loop.

If suppose for the first `td` sample output structrue is as like below, i need to add up all and just display 22 and not the array

```
0 2 0 20
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try with:

```
<?php

if(!empty($bids)) {
  $debitSum  = 0;
  $creditSum = 0;

  foreach ($bids as $bid) {
    $debit  = $bid['Bid']['debit'];
    $credit = $bid['Bid']['credit'];

    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td>' . ( $debit > 0 ? $debit  : '&nbsp;' ) . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . ( $credit> 0 ? $credit : '&nbsp;' ) . '</td>';
    echo '</tr>';

    $debitSum  += $debit;
    $creditSum += $credit;
  }

  echo '<tr style="font-weight: bold">';
  echo '<td>' . $debitSum . '</td>';
  echo '<td>' . $creditSum . '</td>';
  echo '</tr>';

}
?>
```

Edit:

If `$bid['Bid']['debit']` (or credit too) is a string value, then cast it to int value:

```
$debit = (int) $bid['Bid']['debit'];
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you add a counter variable outside the foreach?

```
  <?php
  $total['debit'] = 0;
  $total['credit'] = 0;
  foreach ((array)$bids as $bid)
  {
     $debit = ($bid['Bid']['debit'] > 0)? $bid['Bid']['debit'] : 0;
     $credit = ($bid['Bid']['credit'] > 0)? $bid['Bid']['credit'] : 0;
     $total['debit'] += $debit;
     $total['credit'] += $credit;
     $output =<<<XHTML
     <tr>
         <td>{$debit}</td>
         <td>{$credit}</td>
     </tr>
  XHTML;
     echo $output;
  }
  ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's better to define variable inside the loop and add values to the variable and then print the variable.